# Having trouble loading groovy shell

Tags: groovy

WARNING: ansi will be disabled because an error occurred while installing ansi: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path: /Users/art/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:., /private/var/folders/3r/_tcw73tx7_3655sg006y87w40000gn/T/libjansi-64-7656137315539075820.jnilib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/3r/_tcw73tx7_3655sg006y87w40000gn/T/libjansi-64-7656137315539075820.jnilib, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/3r/_tcw73tx7_3655sg006y87w40000gn/T/libjansi-64-7656137315539075820.jnilib' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,i386', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/3r/_tcw73tx7_3655sg006y87w40000gn/T/libjansi-64-7656137315539075820.jnilib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/3r/_tcw73tx7_3655sg006y87w40000gn/T/libjansi-64-7656137315539075820.jnilib' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,i386', need 'arm64'))]

m1 Mac OS environment.

Reinstall JAVA jdk and resetting groovy version

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message sounds like the native lib `jansi` isn't compiled for your machine.  It's compiled for x86, but you are running on an ARM64.  So Groovy wasn't working on ARM64 until Groovy 4.0.2.  Here is the bug submitted to the Groovy devs:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-10350

So if you have an older version of Groovy you'll have to upgrade to 4.0.2 minimum in order for it to work on Apple M1 processor.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use sdkman to download the latest version but on it the highest is 4.0.11. How do one download a snapshot version on to local machine>

Comment: You don't need to go any higher to get the fixes I discussed.  4.0.11 > 4.0.2 (ie 11 > 2).  Groovy 4.0.11 will work with Apple M1.